# Check table access for Oracle SQL statements in BLOB

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, blob

I have a table with a column containing SQL query (select statements only) in BLOB format.
I'm trying to figure out a way to analyse the SQL queries, and check which tables each SQL queries will be accessing.

Anyone done anything similar?

My thought right now is to create a PLSQL loop that:

1. Converts the BLOB to text to get the SQL query
2. Execute an explain plan for the query
3. Look at the result of the explain plan, and get all the lines with TABLE ACCESS

Edit: I'm on Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit if that helps, and have read-only access to the database, so I'll need to create a solution that's not intrusive to the DB.

Comment: Your approach should work, provided you have privilege to SELECT all the tables. However, why does one store SQL query as `BLOB` rather than `CLOB`?

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit I had the same question. I don't control the data model unfortunately, I can only look at the data that has been stored in the DB..

Answer (score 0):

This could be another simpler method.

Create dynamic views for those SQLs in the BLOB field.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW YOUR_VIEW_NAME AS '|| 
utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(blob_field));
```

Query `user_dependencies` to get the referenced table names.

```
SELECT referenced_name AS table_name 
FROM   user_dependencies 
WHERE  type = 'VIEW' 
       AND NAME = 'YOUR_VIEW_NAME' 
       AND referenced_type = 'TABLE';
```

Comment: Thanks, theoretically would work. I don't have sufficient privileges to create new objects unfortunately, so I need something that can be executed by a read only user.

Comment: @jellyfizz : Are you sure explain plan works for you? You don't have to do all these in production by the way, may be use a test setup which has all the set of tables.

Comment: yeah explain plan works. I'm up to the stage where I can do "execute immediate 'explain plan for ' || c;" already right now, and analysing the result from "SELECT PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY()) where PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT like '%TABLE ACCESS%';". If there's an easier way it would definitely help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is how I have done it:

```
DECLARE
  b BLOB;
  c CLOB;
  n NUMBER;

BEGIN

  -- << loop_through_table >>
  FOR o IN (SELECT TRIM(LABEL) lbl, REQUEST req FROM REQUEST_TABLE) LOOP

      b := o.req;
      IF ((b is null) OR (LENGTH(b)=0)) THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(o.lbl || ' : No query found');
        CONTINUE;
      END IF;

      -- Convert the BLOB to text to get the SQL query
      DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(c,TRUE);
      n:=1;
      -- << loop_through_blob >>
      WHILE (n+32767<=LENGTH(b)) LOOP
        DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND(c,32767,UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(b,32767,n)));
        n:=n+32767;
      END LOOP;
      DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND(c,length(b)-n+1,UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(b,length(b)-n+1,n)));

      -- Execute explain plan
      execute immediate 'EXPLAIN PLAN SET STATEMENT_ID=''temp1'' FOR ' || c;

      -- Look at the result of the explain plan, and get all the lines of OBJECT_TYPE='TABLE'
      -- << loop_through_plan >>
      FOR p IN ( SELECT OBJECT_NAME FROM PLAN_TABLE WHERE STATEMENT_ID='temp1' AND OBJECT_TYPE='TABLE') LOOP
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(o.lbl || ', ' || p.OBJECT_NAME);
      END LOOP;

      execute immediate 'DELETE FROM PLAN_TABLE WHERE STATEMENT_ID=''temp1'' ';

  END LOOP;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-- Completed --');
END;
```